# Basic php/mysql query struggles

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am frustrated and I am beginning to wonder if there is some catch with my hosting company that might be causing this issue.  I have done this type of thing before (not with this hosting company) so I am at a loss.

```
        <?php
    $q = "SELECT * FROM sunsetUsers";
    $r = @mysqli_query($dbh, $q);
    if ($r) {
        echo 'good job';
    } else {
        echo 'you suck';
    }?>
```

The connection info is being called in the header and it works. It will connect to the database and supply me with a good message when I tell it to. Yet, when I try to execute a simple query, I get nothing.  No errors at all other than it tells me, "you suck."  Heh...which is what it should do when the query fails. I am not trying to do anything with the data...I just want to ensure that the query executes with no problems.

Is there any other information I can give that might help here?  This seems really simple to me...yet so confused here as to why this isn't working.

Comment: You're suppressing error by using `@` then wonder why you don't see any errors? Also, look at `mysqlI_error()` to see why your query fails.

Comment: Even when I remove the @ from the query, I still see no errors.

Comment: You should consider making your error messages more positive. Change `you suck` to `Aw, almost got it!`. I sometimes default to `Your mother is ugly` but I'm sure my colleagues would not appreciate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see your mysql errors with `mysql_error` (for the purposes of learning):

```
if (!$r) {
  echo mysqli_error(); // display the last error detected
}
```

Also using the mysql_* & mysqli_* functions are a very old & insecure way of communicating with mysql. Look into [pdo](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059) for a better way.

Comment: Thanks Ben. It tells me that the access was denied for user...
Which is odd since the connection file I am calling will connect to the database just fine.

Comment: Well...I was able to figure out what the problem was. I will look in to the pdo stuff, but I will certainly have to find a better tutorial site than the one listed as it has some errors that other users have pointed out in the comments below. Thanks for at least posting a little help.